# CoreData: Fetch count of to-many relationship with NSDictionaryResultType

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a big list of objects in Core Data (about 50 000 and periodically increasing). I fetch it with the following request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[SongObject name]];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"uid", @"name", @"toArtistRef.uid", @"toArtistRef.name"];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Also entity SongObject contains relationship `toSongsInPlaylistRef`, which is to-many.

I need to fetch count of this set for each object. Due to big amount of data, I can't fetch the relationship itself.
I tried adding
`@"toSongsInPlaylistRef.@count"` and `@"toSongsInPlaylistRef.count"`
but it crashes

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Invalid to many relationship in setPropertiesToFetch: (toSongsInPlaylistRef.count)'
```

Please write any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the count of related object, you have to create a `NSExpressionDescription` 
and include that in the `propertiesToFetch`:

```
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:"
        arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"toSongsInPlaylistRef"]]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"playListCount"]; // Choose an appropriate name here!
[expressionDescription setExpression:countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription, ...];
```

Comment: Just a few hours ago I had a chance to return to this problem and try your suggestion. It perfectly worked. Thank you!

Comment: @hybridcattt: You are welcome, I am glad that it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fetch all songs, but want to fetch their count number, maybe you should add a new property count, which will you increase as you add new song