# Core data - info about to-many relationship properties

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Im a newbie to Core Data, im building kind of a music library app that has two tabs:
*songs* and *artists* tab that shows a list of artists with each artist total songs count and overall song duration (again thats for each artist row)

My core data objects:

```
Song
=====
name
duration
album

artist (to one relationship)


Artist
======
name

songs (to many relationship)
```

So fo now i can managed to show a list of artists, and each artist his total num of songs:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // i know i should reuse the cells..
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    Artist *artist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %lu", artist.name, (unsigned long)artist.songs.allObjects.count];

    return cell;
}
```

**I have two questions:**

1. Is that the right way to fetch the total songs for each artist? when i call `artist.songs.allObjects.count` does core data fetch all the songs? because i really don't need the songs objects..
2. like i said i also need each artist to have the total duration for all its songs, how can i get that? (again without loading all the song objects)

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160032/coredata-fetch-count-of-to-many-relationship-with-nsdictionaryresulttype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not worry about what Core Data does in the background in terms of fetching when you access relationships. Especially in connection with a fetched results controller Core Data will find the best combination of performance and memory footprint. Maybe this is the whole point about having an object graph rather than a relational database.

Still it would be maybe better to skip `allObjects` and to simply call more concisely

```
artists.songs.count
```

Second, for the duration calculation you can take advantage of the fact that all managed objects are key value coding compliant. You can use collective operators like this:

```
NSNumber *totalDuration = [artist.songs valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"];
```

Again, the Core Data framework will make sure you get very efficient and performant code.

Comment: Hi thank u for you answer, wouldn't be too heavy to call @sum for every artist on my list, doesn't it means that it will query the database for each one? maybe there is a way to get the sum for each artist in my original fetch request?

Comment: I don't know what you original fetch request is, but rest assured that the presented code will results in extremely efficient database calls. With the FRC, Core Data will just fetch what it needs to display on screen, a trivial amount of data. The point is that you do not have to worry about it! :) This code will perform OK with 250.000 songs.