# iOS : How to fetch objects with maximum count in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, aggregation, nsfetchrequest

I've two classes in my core data model, and its one to many relationship.

Lets take **Class Album <--->> Class Songs** for the explanation. Now I want to fetch (top) five albums from `Album` which have the maximum no.of `Songs`.

```
Class Album
{
    albumID (Integer)
    name    (String)
    songs   (class B)
}

Class Songs
{
    name   (String)
    length (Integer)
}
```

---

```
@class Songs;
@interface Album : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * albumID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;

@end

@interface Album (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addSongsObject:(Songs *)value;
- (void)removeSongsObject:(Songs *)value;
- (void)addSongs:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSongs:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

---

```
@class Album;

@interface Songs : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * length;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Album *owner;

@end
```

---

Here's what I'm trying,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]]];
fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 0;
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"albumID" ascending:YES]];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF @max.@count.songs"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *albums = [[self context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

If I don't pass predicate, it works fine. But problem is with predicate. It crash the app with following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "SELF @max.@count.songs"'

**Update**: I'm trying the same with `NSExpression` but not able to execute `max:` and `count:` functions together? below is what I've tried,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]]];

fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 0;
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5;

NSError *error = nil;

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"songs"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
//NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *maxCountExpressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[maxCountExpressionDescription setName:@"squishes"];
[maxCountExpressionDescription setExpression:countExpression];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:maxCountExpressionDescription]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSArray *albums = [[self context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I think, I need to query like this,

> SELECT album.name, max(count(album.songs)) FROM Album;

How to create such query in `NSFetchRequest`, is it possible with `NSExpression` or `NSPredicate`?

Comment: in `Class Album`... the `songs` attribute, what kind of class is it...? can you copy the full header file (also with the generated methods) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this in different way, I've added a `songsCount` property into Album class. I'm incrementing/decrement it each time when I add/remove a song from Album. Then I fetch all albums with sorting on `songsCount` in descending order.

Once I can fetch all albums, I'll run a for loop and take out first five objects.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]]];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"songsCount" ascending:NO]];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"songsCount > 0"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *albums = [[self context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSMutableArray *top5Albums = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger totalCounts = [albums count];
NSInteger maxIndex = (totalCounts >= 5) ? 5 : totalCounts;
for(NSInteger index = 0; index < maxIndex; index++) {
    [top5Albums addObject:[albums objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try remove:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF @max.@count.songs"];
```

and replace your sort Descriptors to:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"songs.@count" ascending:NO]];
```

Comment: I'm going to your way, but now this is causing another error, `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle songs.@count'` any idea what's wrong now?

Comment: it looks like this request is too complicated for Core Data. Try with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160032/coredata-fetch-count-of-to-many-relationship-with-nsdictionaryresulttype

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked that too. I'll update my question soon. I want the top 5 out of n no. of albums which have the maximum count of songs. So I think I need to execute some mix query or expressions? How can I combine `max:` & `count:` functions of `NSExpression` together?